# How to get values from a jTextfield at the time of the panel is loaded?

Tags: java, swing, input, runtime, jtextfield

How to get values from a j Textfield at the time of the panel is loaded?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, would you like to clarify it?

Comment: `txtField.getText()` is giving something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the normal way:

`txtField.getText();`

to read the content, but if you are trying to do this on the first load on application start there will be no content set at the time, unless its set in the code "hard coded" in this case it would be possible to read it directly.

Answer (score 0):

> get values from a JTextfield

```
String text = textField.getText();
```